# Is there anyway to run a session of selenium with an exisiting session of a browser

Tags: python, selenium

I was wondering if there is anyway to run selenium with a current session of a browser? Currently, I have a script that uses selenium but once it logs in, the site sends a two-factor authentication since the browser appears to be a new login point. I want to have the script that just updates the fields without having to log in, and just open a new tab of a current browser that is already logged in chrome or firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=executable_path, firefox_options=options, log_path=os.devnull)

url="https://robinhood.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver location")

driver.get(url)

loginBtn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-1tfdro-UnstyledAnchor-Button')

loginBtn.click()

# username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')


def login_rh(usernamef, username, passwordf, password):
    username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10). until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, usernamef)))
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10). until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, passwordf)))
    password_field.send_keys(password)

    submit_button= WebDriverWait(driver, 10). until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "class")))
    submit_button.click()

login_rh("username", "test@gmail.com", "css-a4852m", "passtest")
```

Answer (score 0):

Type :

```
**chrome://version/** in browser you will get executable path of chrome.exe
```

copy this and **close all chrome instance.**

**now  start edge as:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=5555
```

**Now add remote debugging port as:**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:5555");

webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```